# Transforming azimuthal to wgs projection using Python?

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, pyproj, azimuth

I want to plot a circle around a given lat/long with a certain radius on the Earth. The shapefile of the earth has WGS84 coordinate system.

First, I projected the circle to azimuthal equidistant map to apply the real distance on the map and transform it to WGS84. Then, I plotted is as follows:

(with lat=34.2255804,
lon=139.294774527, radius=13006 km)

```
aeqd = pyproj.Proj(proj='aeqd', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84', lat_0=lat, long_0=lon)

wgs = pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

circle = transform(functools.partial(pyproj.transform, aeqd, wgs, Disk(0, 0, radius*1000))
```

[image]

But, when I compared the result with google-radius, the result seemed reverse of my plot as follow:

[image]

Am I missing something when I project or transform the circles? Can anyone explain why it is happened?

Comment: This should be lat=34.2255804, lon=139.294774527. Why doesn't aeqd have the lon_0 and lat_0 parameters set?

Comment: What is the question?  The two results look the same.